# If statement in Matlab function block

Tags: matlab, simulink

Can you write an If statement in a Matlab function block to control an entity switch?

```
If u > 1 
   switch 1
else 
   switch 2 
end
```

Something like this is what I had in mind.

Comment: I should mention that the input coming into the matlab function block is a entity server.

Comment: What do you mean with `switch`? A `goto`/`jump` action to continue the execution at another line? This [link](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26949-matlab-goto-statement) may be relevant, but using normal functions should be preferred.